# "Minecraft Offline.bat" With HD texture pack Fix?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is great:

```
@SET /P IGN=IGN=
@java -Xms512m -Xmx1024 -cp "%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/*" \
    -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/natives" \
    net.minecraft.client.Minecraft %IGN%
```

But if your trying to use any HD texture pack you will get the "unpatched bug" 
i.e. small lava and portal textures on all dirt blocks

is there any way to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

That command line allows Minecraft to use extra memory and use an "offline" player name, but does not itself fix any problems with HD textures.  Make sure you have the [correct mod installed](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/232701-181update-918-mcpatcher-hd-fix-211-01/).

**Update:** I think I just figured out what's going on.  That command pulls in *all* the `.jar` files in your `.minecraft/bin` folder.  Well, it happens that the patcher used by the HD textures fix creates a backup of your original, unmodified `minecraft.jar` file *in that same folder*, which I suspect is conflicting with and overriding your mods.

Find that backup file (it should be `minecraft-1.8.1.jar` if you're using the latest version) and move it somewhere else (or just delete it).  I expect that will get things working again.

Comment: That "script" starts a cmd which allows you to state an IGN= ingame name when mincraft auth servers are down this allwos you to play "offline" but with a Real name in smp . "or for the more cheap cheeky little people to play without paying" My question was allthough this works if your using the HD texture packs
you will recive the "unpatched bug" i.e. small lava and portal textures on all dirt blocks This "play offline.bat" does not access the patched minecraft.jar thus no MC-patcher FIX Any one have some ideas ps: bought mine in beta :P

Comment: It does access the patched minecraft.jar.  It sets the class path with -cp "%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/*"  That is the directory where the minecraft.jar resides (patched or not).  Then it runs the net.minecraft.client.Minecraft class which exists only in the minecraft.jar.  I did a quick look at the MC-patch and it does not edit this class, so my assumption is this should fully work. Can you verify you did in fact install the patch to the "%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar" file?

Comment: indeed i did but it still happens Thats why i decided to sign up here as this is where i found the "script"

Comment: @Garble — I think I've got it.  Updated my answer.

Comment: still no joy removed 1.8.1jar both in admin and user allso tried to patch the admin install no luck wonder what it is

Comment: @Garble — Try running `dir %AppData%\.minecraft\bin\*.jar` at a command line.  You should only see `jinput.jar`, `lwjgl.jar`, `lwjgl_util.jar`, and `minecraft.jar`.  Anything else *could* be causing your problem.  Also double-check that the folder name ("Directory of …") is what you expect it to be.