# How do I set name in Minecraft offline WITH MCPatcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows, minecraft-mcpatcher

Yes, I've seen the other questions of the same problem. I've been using this line:

> java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "Insert Name Here"`

and it's been working beautifully. I've just installed an HD Texture pack with MCPatcher, though. When I load Minecraft normally (either with a paid account or with a generic "Player"), the textures work fine.

Using this line seems to go around the Patcher though and I get some bad textures, important ones are missing, like fire animations and portal blocks. Anyone know Java well enough to edit this line to launch allowing MCPatcher to do its job AND set a custom name?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30776/minecraft-offline-bat-with-hd-texture-pack-fix

Answer (score 1):

> java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "Insert Name Here"

You're almost there but it could not locate the main classes.

Try this:

> @SET /P name here=name here=
>
> @java -Xms512m -Xmx1024 -cp "%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/*" \
>
> -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/natives" \
>
> net.minecraft.client.Minecraft %name here%