# How do I change my player name in Minecraft multiplayer when using MCPatcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mcpatcher

When I connect on my *Minecraft* server, my name is something like "player255", and I spawn in the starting spawn. Can someone tell me how I can change my name on MCPatcher? I want to spawn where I disconnect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set name in Minecraft offline WITH MCPatcher?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56892/how-do-i-set-name-in-minecraft-offline-with-mcpatcher)

Answer (score 2):

Your account name is the name that is displayed. You can only respawn to a bed or the spawn location, not just wher eyou logged out. But you will return there when you log in.

And MC Patcher has nothing to do with either of those. It sounds like you actually need to get a minecraft account from minecraft.net.

Enjoy.